# QTcpSocket - How to go about testing

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm using the QTcpSocket from Qt4 and I've got a method that reads data from the socket using QDataStream and parses it.  The problem is, I want to test that method by simulating a fail if the socket stream was cut off or unexpected data came in.  I'm also trying not to create a QTcpSocket and have some kind of alternate data source such as a file to read from and tie it to the QDataStream.   How would I go about doing this?

For this example's sake, I'm trying to parse data that looks like this

```
"8c8c0000170008000000000000300" //sample data from qtcpSocket.readAll().toHex()
```

**Requirement**:  The answer must use QDataStream, since my parsing logic depends on it since it's tied to the QTcpSocket.

--Skeleton code--

```
void SomeClass::parseMethod(){
QDataStream in;  //tie QDataStream to a source of sample data like a file that contains the example hex string from above

while (!in.end()){
//parse logic goes here
}
```

}

Comment: I kind of agree with odelande, if you are trying to parse messages or some sort of protocol a stream is not necessarily the best way to go. You really want some mechanism to chop your data up into your protocol blocks and then send them off for further decoding / parsing. Why must it use a QDataStream? What is the format of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You can tie a QDataStream to any QIODevice, or even a QByteArray, as in

```
QDataStream in(QByteArray::fromHex("8c8c0000170008000000000000300"));
```

which is great for testing.

By the way, the problem with `QDataStream` over a socket is that you cannot reliably incrementally feed data to it as it arrives through the socket. E.g. if you want to deserialize a float, you have to make sure that enough bytes are available, which is impractical as it forces you to know the details of the encoding.

This suggests the following approach for your protocol. Have a first layer that transfers unstructured `QByteArray`s through the socket, for instance by prefixing them with (a serialized representation of) their size. This first layer incrementally builds each `QByteArray` as individual bytes arrive. Then have a second layer that parses the complete `QByteArray` with a `QDataStream`.

You can then simply test the second layer in isolation by passing in a handwritten `QByteArray` just like above.